# Strategy for troubleshooting complex t-sql query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is my first post here though I have been on the site many times.
I tried finding an answer but didn't find one that addressed my issue.

The T-SQL Query I am working on:

1. Selects around 120 fields,
2. Has around 40 Joins [several of which contain 'Selects']
3. Returns no data.

I don't know the pedigree of the SQL but it MAY have useful logic/joins - and it SHOULD return data.

What is the best way to approach troubleshooting/deciphering the Query?

Thanks!

Having followed suggestions, I found a couple of syntax Errors (missing 'ON' clauses in Join statements) - and I found the Joins that exclude the data. The first one is to a table that is not included in the Select field list. When there is a join to a table from which no rows are returned, is that a 'problem' or is the intention TO use the join to exclude rows? The data itself is new to me at this point or I may not be asking this question.

Thanks!

Comment: You could use CTE's to reduce complexity and to remove the subquery joins. However, you have to understand the query to be able to refactor it completely.

Comment: CTE's in the joins section? And part of my question was HOW to understand [decipher] ... is there an accepted best practice on where to start trying to understand the Query and put the pieces together?

Comment: *"How do you eat an elephant? One bite at a time."*

Comment: Break it down. Comment out everything.  Add One table at a time to the join. See what causes to return an empty result set.

Comment: Thanks, @Amir. And lol @lad2025! :D

Comment: A fairly quick check is for columns from outer joins appearing in a `WHERE` clause without allowing for NULLs. That tends to convert the outer join to an inner join and the results may drop off precipitously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple - one from / join at a time
if the join has a select then test that select

```
select cols 
  from table 
 where =...
```

then

```
select cols 
  from table 
  join table1 
    on 
 where
```

build it up until you get the wrong answer and fix it